# Simple CSS: Moving Object From Line Below To Above

Tags: html, css, whmcs

Im working on a whmcs install and editing the default theme. I'm trying to move a youtube video next to the domain tool, but can't seem to get it to work.

Have a look at: http://jaberminia.com/

Comment: And why did he get downvotes? Seriously.....

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is:

The div that contains the domain input (*prev to the youtube video*):

```
{
    float: left;
    width: 440px; // more or less
}
```

The `input.bigfield` class :

```
input.bigfield {
    width: 80%; // more or less
}
```

Answer (score 0):

??

```
   <div id="video-box" align="right" style="float:left">
```